# Structured Streaming extract most recent values for each id

Tags: apache-spark, dataframe, spark-structured-streaming

I have datastream containing ID, type, and value: For a group of users with given **ID** I receive measurements (**value**s) from different sensors (**type**). 
Example of incoming data:

```
ID type value
1  A    70
2  B    16
1  A    71
2  A    72
```

I need to create Spark Structured Streaming app that will perform custom clustering of the obtained data. However, I am stuck at the begining> I don't know how to create a set of data that will contain the last measurements for each user for each type. I need to have this set for every user that has ever appeared in the system.

So, basically, for a data stream described above, I need a Structured Streaming app that will give me a set of last measurements for every user for every type>

```
  ID type value
  1  A    71
  2  B    16
  2  A    72
```

Users may be inactive for some time, I still need to keep their record. It would be useful if the output is a dataframe.

Any ideas for how to do this will be very welcome.

PS I am fairly new to Spark Structured Streaming, sorry if this is a trivial question.

Comment: Please decide output mode required.

Comment: I think, given the problem, I need a complete output,

Comment: How can really see what the last measurement is? You need timestamp of some sort surely?

Comment: I can add timestamp to each record...

Comment: None the less it will not work.  I tried all tricks, Look at those links, just 2 I checked. not actually realistic to do.

Comment: Unless you can counter, I believe I answered the question.

Comment: Did you resolve?

Comment: @thebluephantom Not exactly. There are workarounds, but nothing clean yet

Comment: If you can refute my answer let me know.

Answer (score 2):

The short answer is: this is **not** possible with Spark Structured Streaming (currently).

Many posts on this and none have suggested a solution that actually works.

When you think about it, in reality it is a tall order.

I tried various approaches - even though I knew it was not possible - and always got some sort of error from Spark. These are documented on Stack Overflow at length. E.g.:

[Structured streaming custom deduplication](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52405751/structured-streaming-custom-deduplication)

[Retain last row for given key in spark structured streaming](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50823468/retain-last-row-for-given-key-in-spark-structured-streaming)

Comment: Would you suggest me to drop Structured Streaming and try to solve this with RDDs? Or there is smarter solution :)

Comment: You could write to data store and read back in to dataframe and process and hence trivial. But not a streaming use case.

Comment: I should not via a streaming use case.